# How to pass flags as argument of urface/cli command?

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I am using [urfave/cli](https://github.com/urfave/cli) to build a CLI application in Go.

What I would like is options given after the first command to be treated as arguments and not flags (so that I can handle them myself or pass them to an other executable).

When using `app.Action` (see below), this is the behavior that I get, but if I am using `cli.Commands` then I get an error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/urfave/cli"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()

    app.Commands = []cli.Command{
        {
            Name:    "test",
            Action:  func(c *cli.Context) error {
                fmt.Println("test", c.Args())
                return nil
            },
        },
    }

    app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {
        fmt.Println(c.Args())
        return nil
    }

    err := app.Run(os.Args)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Output of: `go run main.go cmd -f flag`:

```
[cmd -f flag]
```

but `go run main.go test cmd -f flag` exits with an error where I would like it to oupput

```
test [cmd -f flag]
```

Comment: What is the error you get? It works for me and it outputs `[test cmd -f flag]`!

Comment: I made a typo in the command name (`test2` instead of `test`). The error I get is "Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -f"

Comment: @Abdullah I fixed the typo in my question. You had to enter `go run main.go test2 cmd -f flag` to get the error with the old version.

Comment: You forgot the `app.Name`. Use `go run main.go main test cmd -f flag`. This will output: `[main test cmd -f flag]`

Comment: No I didn't. Maybe I'm not clear enough. I get the error when the command of my program is `test` as defined in `app.Commands`. Any other command, including `main`, will call `app.Action` where there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the documentation of [cli.Command](https://godoc.org/github.com/urfave/cli#Command), there is actually a very simple way to have what I want: setting `SkipFlagParsing` to true will treat all flags as normal arguments.

```
app.Commands = []cli.Command{
    {
        Name:    "test",
        SkipFlagParsing: true
        Action:  func(c *cli.Context) error {
            fmt.Println("test", c.Args())
            return nil
        },
    },
}
```